# Replacing Scalars with their primitive counterparts with graphql-codegen

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

Using `graphql-codegen` to generate Typescript types and operations works like a charm using the `typescript` and `typescript-operations` plugins.

However the `typescript` plugin emits types that use Scalar types instead of primitive types:

```
/** All built-in and custom scalars, mapped to their actual values */
export type Scalars = {
  ID: string;
  String: string;
  Boolean: boolean;
  Int: number;
  Float: number;
};

export type Account = {
  __typename?: 'Account';
  created: Scalars['String'];
}
```

Can graphql-codegen be configured to emit their primitive counterparts instead? Like so:

```
export type Account = {
  __typename?: 'Account';
  created: string; // instead of Scalars['String']
}
```

I've written a custom plugin which drills through all the object's properties, matches correct objects and changes the types, but it is a laborious task. Is there a way to achieve this in a cleaner way?